# Are multiple boost::asio tcp channels faster than a single one?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, tcp, boost-asio

In linux, [`axel`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/axel) is generally faster than [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html). The reason is that `axel` opens multiple channels (connections) to the source and downloads the pieces of a file simultaneously.

So, **the short version of my question is:** Would doing the same with boost::asio make the connection transfer data faster?

By looking at these simple examples of a [client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp) and a [server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp), I could make a single connection initiate multiple client instances, and connect to the same server with multiple sessions. In the communication protocol, I can make the client and server ready for such connections in such a way, where data is split among all the connection channels.

Could someone please explain to me why this should or shouldn't work out based on the scenarios I drew?

Please ask for more details if you need it.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://superuser.com/questions/261663/why-is-multi-thread-downloading-faster-than-single-thread) to understand, when multi-channel download can be faster that single-channel. If neither of these reasons is applicable in your case, you should be able to get a decent throughput with a single socket.

Comment: @Igor actually there doesn't seem to be a single conclusive answer there. For example, would latency be really a factor? If yes, then splitting the connection definitely makes it faster.